# How to implement GWT print preview?

Tags: gwt, printing, preview

I have a GWT web app with multiple GWT widgets and panels. I need to introduce a print preview functionality for my web page. In print preview the web page should display only plain text and hide all GWT UI generated code (tables , menus etc..)

I wonder what is the best approach to implement GWT Print preview functionality?

thanks much

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a stylesheet that accomplishes what you need, and switch it on for printing and print preview only.

Comment: yes that's what i thought about too. maybe maintaining a global List of my GWT widgets and set their style names for print preview ?

Comment: I think it's easier to make sure all your GWT widgets (those that you want to hide anyway) have a certain CSS class, say, `noprint`. Then in your print stylesheet, add a rule like `.noprint { visibility: none !important; }`

Comment: I'm not very experienced in css. what will the last css rule do as logic? if i set my widgets that i want to hide to use noprint style .how does my widgets knows they need to hide without any GWT code? thanks

Comment: i thought a about a strategy to implement print view:

we could maintain a Global variable boolean "print' that we can set to 'false' or 'true' at run time (false by default) .
for the GWT components that we need to hide in print view mode; we could write a onLoad() method for each of these gwt components . in onLoad() we set the component css style name according to 'print' variable.
To switch to print view we set 'print' variable to 'true' and reload the GWT web app .
what you think about this approach? is it possible to implement? is there a better approach?

Comment: That rule makes all elements in your HTML invisible that hace 'noprint' in their class attribute. You don't need any extra code, except a snippet that includes the stylesheet containing this rule only when a print or print preview is required.

Comment: what will the snippet look like?